# Bulk delete Facebook posts created by an app

Tags: facebook

I need to remove a bunch of spam posts from my Facebook pages wall. The method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342658/is-there-a-way-to-delete-all-facebook-wall-posts-prior-to-a-specified-date) won't work because the posts were coming from an RSS auto-posting app.

I'm surprised there isn't an app that will let you do this, Twitter has lots of apps for bulk deleting tweets.

Comment: I don't have any experience using it but could [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) be what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

When you deauthorize an app in your [Facebook application settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), you have the option of deleting posts made by that app. Click the "X" to the far right of the application listing, then choose "Delete all app activity".

[image: Delete all app activity]

In general, you can also go through your timeline by looking at:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<your_access_token>&fields=id,application
```

For each entry, find the ones whose application ID matches the app in question, and then delete them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to de-authorize the app which is auto posting RSS feeds and there will come the option to delete all activity. Check it & click OK.